# Missing strackrace in New Relic APM when using Spring WebFlux

Tags: exception, trace, spring-webflux, newrelic, apm

Missing strackrace in New Relic APM when using Spring WebFlux

I use Spring WebFlux 5.2.3 and Java Agent 5.9.0. When error occurs on `APM` > `Events` > `Errors` I can only see brief error message:

```
Error message
Internal Server Error: Internal Server Error
```

Whereas on logs I can see full stacktrace:

```
2020-01-30 13:12:30.797 ERROR 25562 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [1722358b]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/api"

com.exampe.SomeException: Some message...
    at [ ... ]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/api" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        [ ... ]
        at com.example.MyController.handle(MyController.kt:27) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1637) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:247) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:329) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1637) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:330) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1637) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:209) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:367) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:363) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:489) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:90) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:211) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321) ~[netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295) ~[netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

When I use `spring-web` everything works fine, and stacktrace is present.

I wonder if it's a bug or I miss some configuration.